# Disable Button while AJAX Request

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to disable a button after it's clicked. I have tried:

```
$("#ajaxStart").click(function() {
    $("#ajaxStart").attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/jQueryTest/test.json',
      data: {
        action: 'viewRekonInfo'
      },
      type: 'post',
      success: function(response){
        //success process here                             
        $("#alertContainer").delay(1000).fadeOut(800);
       },
      error: errorhandler,
      dataType: 'json'
    });    
    $("#ajaxStart").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

but the button is not getting disabled. When I remove `$("#ajaxStart").attr("disabled", false);`    the button gets disabled.

While this is not working as expected, I think the code sequence is correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sadly, none of the answers here work if preventing the user from clicking again takes longer than it takes the user to perform another click. E.g., if the user clicks very quickly (either purposefully or accidentally) multiple times before we either disable the button or dynamically add an element on top of it, then multiple clicks will be registered. Haven't found a solution to this yet.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Put `$("#ajaxStart").attr("disabled", false);` inside the success function:

```
$("#ajaxStart").click(function() {
    $("#ajaxStart").attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/jQueryTest/test.json',
        data: { 
            action: 'viewRekonInfo'
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            //success process here
            $("#alertContainer").delay(1000).fadeOut(800);

            $("#ajaxStart").attr("disabled", false);
        },
        error: errorhandler,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

This will ensure that disable is set to false **after** the data has loaded... Currently you disable and enable the button in the same click function, ie at the same time.

Comment: Actually, I would put it inside the `complete` callback, because if the request fail, I dont necessarily want the button to stay disabled.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you just disable & enable the button on the same button click,.

You have to enable it inside the completion of AJAX call

something like this

```
           success: function(response){
                    $("#ajaxStart").attr("disabled", false); 
                       //success process here
                       $("#alertContainer").delay(1000).fadeOut(800);
                   },
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this by defining two jquery functions:

```
var showDisableLayer = function() {
  $('<div id="loading" style="position:fixed; z-index: 2147483647; top:0; left:0; background-color: white; opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
  $("#loading").height($(document).height());
  $("#loading").width($(document).width());
};

var hideDisableLayer = function() {
    $("#loading").remove();
};
```

The first function creates a layer on top of everything. The reason the layer is white and completely opaque, is that otherwise, IE allows you to click through it.

When doing my ajax, i do like this:

```
$("#ajaxStart").click(function() {          
   showDisableLayer(); // Show the layer of glass.
   $.ajax({              
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/jQueryTest/test.json',              
      data: {                   
          action: 'viewRekonInfo'              
      }, 
      type: 'post',              
      success: function(response){                  
         //success process here                  
         $("#alertContainer").delay(1000).fadeOut(800);                                     
         hideDisableLayer(); // Hides the layer of glass.
      },
      error: errorhandler,              
      dataType: 'json'          
   });      
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using global function of ajax

```
            $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
        });
```

here is documentation [link](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/).

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ajax()` call "will not block" -- that means it will return immediately, and then you enable the button immediately, so the button is not disabled.

You can enable the button when the AJAX is successful, has error, or is otherwise finished, by using `complete`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> complete(XMLHttpRequest,
> textStatus)
>
> A function to be
> called when the request finishes
> (after success and error callbacks are
> executed). The function gets passed
> two arguments: The XMLHttpRequest
> object and a string categorizing the
> status of the request ("success",
> "notmodified", "error", "timeout", or
> "parsererror"). This is an Ajax Event.