# Stop the ability to click a button for a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button for next and a button for previous in my webpage, when i click one of them some data should be loaded into the page . i want to stop the ability of clicking those buttons while the data is loading. can i do that???

```
<div class="final_dates_container">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="left"><a href="#" onclick="prev_date();"><img class="left_image" src="./include-images/left_arrow.png"/></a></td>

                    <td class="right"><a href="#" onclick="next_date();"><img class="right_image" src="./include-images/right_arrow.png"/></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Disable the buttons as the first line of the onClick handler - and re-enable them when your data is loaded.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622499/disable-button-while-ajax-request

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are using `ajax` then you can `disable` other `buttons` like

**Prev click Function**

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    beforeSend:function(){
       $('#next').prop('disable',true);// disable next button
    }
    success:function(){
       //your code
       $('#next').removeAttr('disable');// remove disable attribute from here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by using ajax global function

```
            $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
        });
```