# the same row in mysql(nginx+tornado+mysqldb)

Tags: python, mysql, tornado

I use tornado for my web app. The mysqldb is used for insert data into mysql5.1.
In production environment,there has a nginx+ upstream with 10 tornado process.
When the network is slow，the user will double click the button and post the same json data a tornado handler, sometimes there will generate two rows with same data in mysql. Actually,I hava used the mysqldb transcation and test the logic. it's ok in development environment(one tornado process).

My Code:

```
    import MySQLdb
    hostname = options.mysql_host
    uid = options.mysql_user
    database = options.mysql_database
    pwd = options.mysql_password
    port = 3306
    newid=-1
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=hostname, user=uid,db=database,passwd=pwd,port=int(port),use_unicode=True,charset="utf8")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    try:

       sql_query = "select ID from ATable where USER_ID = "+str(_user_id)+" and START_DATE_LOCAL = '"+str(_start_date_local)+"' and FLAG = 1"
       cursor.execute(sql_query)
       results_query = cursor.fetchone()

       if results_query is not None:
          newid =int(results_query[0])
       else:
          #do insert
          sql="insert into ATable..."
          print sql

          cursor.execute(sql)
          newid = int(conn.insert_id())

       conn.commit()

    except Exception,e:
       print 'ERROR:',e
       conn.rollback()

    conn.close()
    return newid
```

I think my code is right.
There may have something wrong with nginx or mysql5.1?

Should I config the ip_hash in nginx upstrem for this handler?

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition. It's easier to see in production because you're posting over a higher-latency network, so you have more time to click the button twice before the first INSERT completes. The typical solution is to make the button disable itself using Javascript *before* it posts to the server, to prevent double-clicking. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4622521/618967) for an example of disabling a button while waiting for an AJAX request to complete.