# Durandal & Knockout: Disable Button while ajax Request

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I have multiple buttons that are bound to click Events:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
    data-bind="click: clickAction.bind($data, 'start')">Start
</button>
```

The clickAction does some ajax queries, depending on the given parameter ("start"). Now i want to disable this button while the request is loading...
How can i access the property like this:

```
// pseudo code
function clickAction(actionType) {
    $(senderButton).prop('disabled', true);
    // HERE SOME AJAX STUFF
    $(senderButton).prop('disabled', false);
}
```

EDIT:
I made it with the knockout 'enabled' binding:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
    data-bind="click: clickAction.bind($data, 'start'), enable: !isLoading()">Start
</button>
```

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622499/disable-button-while-ajax-request

Comment: knockout has a `disable` binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your view like this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
    data-bind="click: clickAction.bind($data, 'start'), disable: ajaxInProgress">Start
</button>
```

Then in your view model, you define an `ajaxInProgress` observable:

```
var ajaxInProgress = ko.observable(false);
```

You will need to expose that observable in the view model as well.

In your `clickAction` event handler, you need to set the observable to `true` before sending the AJAX request, and then back to `false` when the response is received:

```
this.clickAction = function (actionType) {
    ajaxInProgress(true);
    // possibly incorrect jQuery AJAX call syntax...
    $.get({
        // ... URL, method, and other params ...
        success: function () {
            ajaxInProgress(false);
            // ... other actions when data is loaded ...
        },
        error: function () {
            ajaxInProgress(false);
            // ... other error handling ...
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I am not doing `ajaxInProgress(false)` on the line after the `$.get` call because that happens immediately after the request is sent, instead of waiting until the response is received.  It has to be in the callback.

Comment: I already implemented the observable 'isLoading', which is working quite similar. My problem was primarily the binding to the button... so the 'enable: !isLoading()' and the 'disable: inProgress' are both working.